# Bugzilla not sending emails, even to the test file?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, perl, bugzilla

I have installed and setup Bugzilla3 for my domain.
Everything is working properly except for the email functionality.

The server uses Postfix, and that works for my PHP application, and command line.

In Bugzilla, I have tried setting the **mail_delivery_method** to 'test', and nothing shows up in **data/mailer.testfile**, it is completely blank...

I have no idea where to go from here, any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Look into the log files. What's there?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, zilch, nada. The mail.log files shows no activity, and the data/mailer.testfile still contains nothing (even though the purpose of the file is to display Bugzilla 'test' emails).

Comment: So then I would file a bug in the bugzilla of bugzilla.

Comment: Yes I file bugs, and change them to try and generate some emails, does not work.

Comment: 1. Check the status of jobs in queue: `/etc/init.d/bugzilla.queue`
2. fire, `tail -f /var/log/maillog`

Answer (score 1):

**Check you have given a valid email address in "mailfrom" parameter.**

I also have this similar issue, after I gave a valid email address it worked fine.

*Additional Information:*

I have installed postfix in my system and selected "Sendmail" in mail_delivery_method.

Answer (score 0):

When you change bugs, does Bugzilla tell you that it is sending mail? By default, if you change a bug, mail is not sent to you, only to other people - and if you are the only user of your Bugzilla, that would be no-one :-)

To force a mail to be generated, ask for a password reset and then check the mailer.testfile.

Which version of Bugzilla are you using?

Gerv

Comment: Version 3.something. I have it set to send mail, and when I edit/change bugs it tells me its sending an email to my address. Even on testing though it doesn't show anything in the test file... I will test the password reset and get back to you.

Comment: donutdan: any news?

Comment: have not been able to get it to work yet... Not too worried about it however, we are surviving without the email functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I know this must have been resolved by now, but I had a similar issue where I couldn't find the mailer.testfile and had just assumed it wasn't being created.

It turns out I was looking in the wrong directory.

The correct (default) location for this file is:

```
/var/lib/bugzilla/data
```

Originally I was looking in a data directory I created under:

```
/usr/share/bugzilla
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue, bugzilla was showing that it sent the email but nothing was received

fixed by setting: use_mailer_queue to "off"

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue that was related to the mailer_queue option after a reboot. Note the description that states it requires a daemon to be started.

We started this daemon and set a startup task and resolved the issue